# CosmosDB Upsert throws error Entity with id already exists when it does not

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmosdb collection. Entries have an id and a partition key. The id is a 6 digit string (like `123456`) and the partition key is the first two digits as a string (like `12`). I want to upsert a document. The collection has no entries.

I have a queue-triggered azure function that connects to the document db.

When I call

```
Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(link, item)
```

I get an error telling me that an entry already has that id.

Comment: Mind showing us what the `link` and the `item` objects look like?

Comment: Does the item contain the attributes for the Partition Key?